# Display the gps topic in a bag file

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS Community

As is shown in the title, I have recorded some gps data using ublox device in a bag file, which can be seen by rostopic echo. However, I am wondering how can I be able to dispaly the gps data (probably on google map or somewhere else).

Regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282228/display-the-gps-topic-in-a-bag-file/) by [Teddy_NTU](https://answers.ros.org/users/33489/teddy_ntu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2018-02-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-09**:
This seems like a duplicate of #q276809.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

you have two solutions to do this:

1. use mapviz http://wiki.ros.org/mapviz , which has a plugin to visualize GPS messages and another got maps such as google (I use also https://github.com/danielsnider/MapViz-Tile-Map-Google-Maps-Satellite )
2. You can do something similar on RViz using this plugin https://github.com/gareth-cross/rviz_satellite
   and http://wiki.ros.org/navsat_odometry

---

Originally posted by [Davide Faconti](https://answers.ros.org/users/578/davide-faconti/) with karma: 308 on 2018-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0